# What type of single-phase motors can I control using a frequency inverter?

Tags: motor-controller, fan, ac-motor

I have a [single phase fan](https://catalog.pelonistechnologies.com/Asset/FS133.pdf), and I want to control the speed of this fan so it occurred to me to design a VFD for this purpose, but I was researching more about single phase AC motors and I read that there are several types of single phase motors, so before designing anything I would like to know what type of single-phase motors can be controlled using a VFD and if it is possible to know if the fan I have can be controlled by a VFD, I hope you can help me,

Regards.

---

I am attaching a picture of the way the motor is connected, originally the L1 and L2 wires were connected to a dimmer but I want to connect the L1 and L2 wires to the VFD to control the motor, is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Yes, there are several types. Which one is yours?

Comment: That is a capacitor start induction motor.

Comment: Ohh if you’re designing a vfd you could try an experiment I’ve been meaning to do: build a 2 phase vfd and eliminate the capacitor

Comment: Careful the start coil probably is not rated for continuous use.